# Record all the immediate predecessors in the BFS algorithm

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I'm tasked to print out all the predecessors that is connected to the current vertex after executing a BFS search in a given graph. However, I encountered a problem in my code in which it only prints out the last explored predecessor.

```
pred = {}
level = {}

def bfs(G, S):
    kyu = deque([S])
    pred[S] = []
    level[S] = 0
    while len(kyu) > 0:
        curr = kyu.popleft()
        neighbors = G[curr]
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            if neighbor not in pred:
                pred[neighbor] = curr
                level[neighbor] = level[curr] + 1  # added
                kyu.append(neighbor)


def bfs_runner(G):
    components = 0
    for v in G:
        if v not in pred:
            components += 1
            bfs(G, v)
    return components
```

**SAMPLE INPUT:**

```
G = {
     'A': ['B'],
     'B': ['A', 'C', 'D'],
     'C': ['B', 'E'],
     'D': ['B', 'E'],
     'E': ['C', 'D']
}
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
pred = {
      'A': [],
      'B': ['A'],
      'C': ['B'],
      'D': ['B'],
      'E': ['C', 'D']
}
```

**MY OUTPUT:**

```
pred = {
      'A': [],
      'B': ['A'],
      'C': ['B'],
      'D': ['B'],
      'E': ['C']
}
```

Comment: "all the predecessors after executing a bfs search in a given graph", so with that shouldn't it be `'E': ['A', 'B', 'C']` ?

Comment: @python_user My mistake, predecessors are previous vertices connected to the current vertex.

Comment: so you mean all immediate predecessors?

Comment: @python_user Exactly!

Comment: ok, let me see if I change my algorithm

Comment: @python_user Sure thing!

Comment: in the mean time maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168641/breadth-first-search-all-paths

Comment: @python_user I'm sorry, the code in the link you have provided is a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
pred = defaultdict (list)
level = defaultdict (lambda: 0)

def bfs(G, S):
    kyu = deque([S])
    while len(kyu) > 0:
        curr = kyu.popleft()
        neighbors = G[curr]
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            if neighbor not in pred:
                pred[neighbor].append(curr)
                level[neighbor] = level[curr] + 1  # added
                kyu.append(neighbor)
```

Explanation: You were overwriting the value of `pred[neighbor]` instead of appending to it. `defaultdict(list)` automatically initializes `pred[neighbor]` to an empty list if neighbor is not yet in pred. Similarly for level.

Note: Done from my mobile. Did not test.

EDIT:

Complete rewrite:

```
from collections import deque, defaultdict
   
def get_predecessors(G, S):
    visited = set()
    predecessors = defaultdict(set)
    kyu = deque([S])
    while len(kyu) > 0:
        current_node = kyu.popleft()
        if current_node in visited:
            continue
        
        visited.add(current_node)
        nodes = G[current_node]
        for node in nodes:
            predecessors[node].add(current_node)
            if not node in visited:
                kyu.append(node)
                
    return predecessors

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    G = {
         'A': ['B'],
         'B': ['A', 'C', 'D'],
         'C': ['B', 'E'],
         'D': ['B', 'E'],
         'E': ['C', 'D']
    }
    
    result = get_predecessors(G, 'A')
    print(dict(result))
```

Output:

```
{'B': {'A', 'C', 'D'},
 'A': {'B'},
 'C': {'B', 'E'},
 'D': {'B', 'E'},
 'E': {'C', 'D'}}
```

Comment: Your code's output is pretty much similar to mine: `{'B': ['A'], 'A': ['B'], 'C': ['B'], 'D': ['B'], 'E': ['C']})` except key `'A'` is wrong.

Comment: Note that I did not radically modify your algorithm. Just fixed parts that I thought would cause problems. It seems that more work is needed to get this fixed. Will do once home with a PC in hand.

Comment: Your desired input seems completely off BTW. Look at my latest edit.

Comment: I think I forgot one crucial information of the problem, the function takes a source vertex then will do BFS from there.

Comment: This assumption implies that there are cycles that will eventually lead to every other connected node. You can easily modify the provided code by passing the vertex in question and initializing the queue with that single vertex. It should work like a charm.

Comment: I've set `kyu = deque([S])`, however, it still outputs the same as before.

Comment: I have modified the latest code I provided to start from any vertex. I called the traversal function passing `G` and `'A'`. I get the same result. However, you have no guarantee of getting the same output unless there exists a path from the initial vertex to every other vertex. I did not check that.

Comment: If my solution worked mark as answered and upvote.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe you've misunderstood the problem. While performing BFS from the source vertex to last level of the graph, that's the time the predecessor gets recorded

Comment: "print out all the predecessors that is connected to the current vertex after executing a BFS search in a given graph". I assume what you mean by *current vertex* is the vertex you call the function with along with the graph. After doing the bfs traversal, the dictionary being returned contains the predecessors of each vertex in the graph. To get the predecessor of that particular vertex, you just access the returned dictionary with the said vertex as a key. If you are looking for something else, then I am not sure your question is clear.